# Error missing end time when create event on google calendar api using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-apis-explorer

I have a problem creating an event in google calendar api using nodejs. Specifically, I successfully took a list of events in the google calendar but could not create the event and it showed a "**Missing end time**" error. Below is my code, I have reference to the [google calendar api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events) instructions:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/calendar-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH || process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'quickstart.json';
console.log(TOKEN_PATH);

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
        return;
    }
    // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
    // Google Calendar API.
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), listEvents);
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), addEvents);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
    var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
    var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
    var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
    var auth = new googleAuth();
    var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
        if (err) {
            getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
        } else {
            oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
            callback(oauth2Client);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
    var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES
    });
    console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
    var rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });
    rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
        rl.close();
        oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
                return;
            }
            oauth2Client.credentials = token;
            storeToken(token);
            callback(oauth2Client);
        });
    });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
    try {
        fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
            throw err;
        }
    }
    fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
    console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

/**
 * Lists the next 10 events on the user's primary calendar.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listEvents(auth) {
    var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
    calendar.events.list({
        auth: auth,
        calendarId: 'primary',
        timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
        maxResults: 10,
        singleEvents: true,
        orderBy: 'startTime'
    }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        var events = response.items;
        if (events.length == 0) {
            console.log('No upcoming events found.');
        } else {
            console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
            for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                var event = events[i];
                var start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
                var end = event.end.dateTime || event.end.date;
                console.log('%s - %s', start, event.summary);
                console.log('%s', end);
            }
        }
    });
}

function addEvents(auth){
    var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
    var event = {
        'summary': 'Drinking beer with friends',
        'start': {
            'dateTime': '2018-02-09T09:00:00+07:00'
        },
        'end': {
            'dateTime': '2018-02-09T17:00:00+07:00'
        }
    };
    calendar.events.insert({
        auth: auth,
        calendarId: 'primary',
        resource: event,
    }, function(err, event) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('There was an error contacting the Calendar service: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Event created: %s', event.htmlLink);
    });
}


/* GET home page. */
/*console.log('ok');
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });

});*/

module.exports = router;
```

I tried to fix but the code still says **"Missing end time"** error when I create event, 1 week elapsed I can not fix it yet. Looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes -

1. `var {google} = require('googleapis');` instead of `var google = require('googleapis');`
2. Write `var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;` instead of `var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');`
3. Do not `npm install google-auth-library`. If you did, remove it from your package.json and do `npm install` again.
4. Make sure you have the latest version of `googleapis` package. If you do not - do `npm install googleapis@27` to get it. (Also add it to the package.json for future).
5. For any callback - instead of `response.items`, do `response.data.items`. You do not necessarily need the callback output when you create an event but you definitely need it when you list events. So do not forget to make this change there.

I don't think there would be any issue once you follow all these steps. If there still is, just reply to this. I will try my best to get it resolved!

Comment: Thank you your answer but I have a new problem. All problems I shared bellow.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I am just revoked my access from Third-party apps with account access. and it's work for me